# Javascript to convert address to latitude and longtitude in seperate search boxes

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude

I am creating an search tool, which works as an html file with buttons. The html file is offline until you push one of the buttons, after which the tool connects to the internet and makes the search.

I would like make an address search page, where the user can enter an address, after which the latitude and longtitude of this address is put into boxes, so they can be used for searches on different sites.

Something like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Akp.png)

Any help is appreciated. I hope there is a way of doing this form open source material, so I can avoid using google API keys.

Comment: `offline search tool` .... `enter an address, after which the latitude and longtitude of this address` ... you'll need a database of every single address in the world along with its coordinates, and that will need to be included in your code, since this is an `offline` search tool

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of geocoder, as in an API that has street names, districts, postcodes .. etc.

Google API provides that but I understand that you don't want to use it anymore because it is priced.

There are a few free options if that's what you are looking for, for example:

- Nominatim (Fully Free Open Source and Offline)
- MapBox (Limited Free),
- PositionStack (Limited Free).

You have to decide on one of them and read their APIs on how to implement them.

Comment: He wants an offline tool.

Comment: @GabeRAMturn Nominatim could work tho I wonder about accuracy.

Comment: I have edited to post for clarity. Only offline until you push the button. So it would be ok to connect to the internet to get the lat long.